# Plotting polyhedra faces with polygons removed from the interiors of the faces

Tags: plotting, graphics, polyhedra

I have dozens of vertices and dozens of faces which is why I use the `v={};i={}` and `Graphics3D` and `GraphicsComplex`, which I'll keep for the below example even though it's not necessary in this case. Also I'll specify `x,y,z` points even though below I'm not using the `z` dimension.

I'm trying to remove an interior polygon from a face. When I was working with 2D I could specify a colored polygon and then specify an interior white polygon and the latter would override the former, but that's not working for me in 3D. I probably just have it set up wrong.

This is what doesn't work:

```
v = {{0, 0, 0}, {10, 0, 0}, {10, 10, 0}, {0, 10, 0}, {2, 2, 0}, {2, 5, 0}, {5, 5, 0}, {5, 2, 0}};
i = {{1, 2, 3, 4}};
{Graphics3D[{Red, GraphicsComplex[v, Polygon[i]]} ]    ;   
 i = {{5, 6, 7, 8}}; 
 Graphics3D[{White, GraphicsComplex[v, Polygon[i]]}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Graphics3D[Normal@PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "Faces"] /. 
           p : Polygon[__] :> {RandomChoice[{Red, White, Blue, Transparent}], p},
           Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand this. I want a 10 by 10 square with a 3 by 3 square inside of it removed. Maybe I'm not putting your answer in the right place. This is what I did:       v = {{0, 0, 0}, {10, 0, 0}, {10, 10, 0}, {0, 10, 0}, {2, 2, 0}, {2, 5,
     0}, {5, 5, 0}, {5, 2, 0}};
i = {
   {1, 2, 3, 4}};
{Graphics3D[{Red, GraphicsComplex[v, Polygon[i]]} ]    ;   
 i = {{5, 6, 7, 8}}; 
 Graphics3D[{White, GraphicsComplex[v, Polygon[i]]}, 
  Lighting -> "Neutral"]}

Comment: I'm new to this. I don't know what "rep points" are. I just posted this question at community.wolfram.com and attached it there.

Comment: Now that I tried to move this discussion to chat, I see what "rep points" are--and that I have 1, not enough to chat.   Community.wolfram.com had an "Attachments"/"Add a file to this post" so that's what I did.     Why don't you post your answer there?